# ASP.NET - ActionResult parameter is coming back null always when passing string - why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am barely starting out with my first project on the ASP.NET MVC project type and I am creating a Details page where instead of passing the templated (int id), I would like to pass a string instead.  But when I am in debug mode, and enter this in the URL, "myString" is null.  Why so?  Do I have to change anything else somehwere else?

So if I go to the URL and enter this:

http://localhost:2345/Bank/EmployeeDetails/3d34xyz

```
public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(string myString) // myString is null
{
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In you `Global.asax.cs` file, you will have the following route mapped by default:

```
routes.mapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

That means that an url like `http://localhost:2345/Bank/EmployeeDetails/3d34xyz` will go to the `Bank` controller, the `EmployeeDetails` action and pass the value `3d34xyz` into a parameter named `id`. It is perfectly alright to pass a string, but in order to make it work you have two options:

1) Rename the variable to `id` in your action method.

```
public ActionResult EmployeeDetails(string id) { ... }
```

2) Add another route that matches whatever name you want for your string. Make sure to make it more specific than the default route, and to place it *before* the default route in the `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
routes.mapRoute(
    "BankEmployeeDetails"
    "Bank/EmployeeDetails/{myString}"
    new { controller = "Bank", action = "EmployeeDetails", myString = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This will pass a default value of `null` to `myString` if no value is passed in the url, but with the url you specified you will pass the value `3d34xyz`.

Comment: Just fyi, I did find a small error in my post: if you choose option 2 and add a new route, it should be more _specific_ than the default route, not more _general_ as I originally stated. This is because the MVC Framework will go through the routes in order, and grab the first one that matches - so you want to make sure that only the url:s that are relevant match the new route.

Comment: just an fyi for anyone looking `id = null` might be `id = UrlParameter.Optional` depending on your version of .NET

Comment: @MaximusPeters: Thanks - probably no-one getting here today will use a version where `null` is the right way to do it :)

Comment: Thanks so much @Tomas Lycken - this helped me with my issue as well.

Answer (score 5):

Rename `myString` to `id` if you are using the default route table.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you haven't modified the default routes (In your Global.asax.cs):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

**The method is expecting it to be named "id".**

Answer (score 4):

Change the name of `myString` to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you just need to provide the id in the page where you the hyperlink for Details(in the Bank page here)

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=""})
```

This solved my problem hope it helps you.

This for MVC 5.

Comment: This does not work in this case, his parameter name is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

And when you have tryed all of them and still it comes back null then give a full restart for Visual Studio. That's what eventually helped for me.