# ASP MVC Areas and ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm working on a new project where I want to use Phil Haack Areas (1) idea + Steve Sanderson's tweak (2).  I have a simple root view with an action link to a view an area (Foo).  The URL that is generated has the proper area, but it appends the root controller (Bar) at the end.  Here's my root view code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo Index Page", "Index", new { area="Foo" } )%>

</asp:Content>
```

and here's the URL that it generates:

localhost:6494/Foo/Bar

Any idea why the "/Bar" is on there?

(1): [haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx)

(2): [blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found a solution.  I don't think it is appropriate, so I will ask for an improvement.  By specifying a controller name, I can get the URL to form properly.  I.E.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<%= Html.ActionLink("Foo Index Page", "Index", new { area="Foo", controller="Baz" } )%>

</asp:Content>
```

Once I did this, then the URL was correct

localhost:6494/Foo

Why is this a problem?  Phil's demo uses the controller with the name HomeController.  I don't know (because I can't trace) how the Html.ActionLink() method goes about constructing the URL; but it looks as if it is relying on a default case of HomeController existing, which I don't have.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to allow for Controllers not named Home to be the default, please reply.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To not have `Home` as the default controller name, simply [change the default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849624/asp-net-actionresult-parameter-is-coming-back-null-always-when-passing-string/849666#849666).

Answer (score 0):

@Joe

In your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file you have to change value for default controller from Home to whatever you like :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "NAME_OF_YOUR_HOME_CONTROLLER", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```