# Object passing with jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass object to controller action, but it does not work. Object is null, no error. I debugged it and I got the passing parameters.

scripts

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var IrregularChartParams = {
    MeterId: 2,
    MeterTypeId: 2,
    ReadingTypeId: 4,
    StartDate: "start",
    EndDate: "end",
    DateRangeId: 5
};

var chartParams= JSON.stringify(IrregularChartParams);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: app_base_url + 'Graph/GetChart',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: chartParams,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#chart").html(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("hatalı");
    }
});
});
```

controller

```
public ActionResult _IrregularChart(IrregularChartParams chartParams)
{
    // chartParams is null 
}
```

debugging time params looking like following:

> - Params  {%7b%22MeterId%22%3a2%2c%22MeterTypeId%22%3a2%2c%22ReadingTypeId%22%3a4%2c%22StartDate%22%3a%22start%22%2c%22EndDate%22%3a%22end%22%2c%22DateRangeId%22%3a5%7d&**FunnelWeb**=44D66957AF9E021D68F011F7EA89CF99585363E067264B4A9B2B60FB51030DFA64EAA943529D3352875332394F24293162CBFE088352F1169202E0806155F66F370237D16A787AB8E76417B72808F34FEC9B5133D1D56D0839B614F2E231AB8DE23FE3BB7C048BAA3FCEEDABD4A2A6ACCB1D76DEB657B3B8575A664823DA24044F67C096206D04CBD5971BAE21684EA3FE2CAA747A1C8C563692DBE6335A0948&.ASPXAUTH=C42E113D8E4C49775DE2172054A1D505B777F691EEDA493FBD1B982148F59ECB28D730ED46E19F8BD3AF7A37046D73D462907AF535ED2DC3F80CD6B9681717D9DAD7BD919FAA8BD57B5C7A6EACC0E0EDE956004762C1BD2E76F9D26B9C4036B0A4C903DC02BCFEE341151D6E0A35D748CE4D4FB3C1B84FF58A196E85F78477DF&ALL_HTTP=HTTP_CONNECTION%3akeep-alive%0d%0aHTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH%3a99%0d%0aHTTP_CONTENT_TYPE%3aapplication%2fx-www-form-urlencoded%3b+charset%3dUTF-8%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT%3a*%2f*%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET%3aISO-8859-9%2cutf-8%3bq%3d0.7%2c*%3bq%3d0.3%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING%3agzip%2cdeflate%2csdch%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE%3atr-TR%2ctr%3bq%3d0.8%2cen-US%3bq%3d0.6%2cen%3bq%3d0.4%0d%0aHTTP_COOKIE%3aFunnelWeb%3d44D66957AF9E021D68F011F7EA89CF99585363E067264B4A9B2B60FB51030DFA64EAA943529D3352875332394F24293162CBFE088352F1169202E0806155F66F370237D16A787AB8E76417B72808F34FEC9B5133D1D56D0839B614F2E231AB8DE23FE3BB7C048BAA3FCEEDABD4A2A6ACCB1D76DEB657B3B8575A664823DA24044F67C096206D04CBD5971BAE21684EA3FE2CAA747A1C8C563692DBE6335A0948%3b+.ASPXAUTH%3dC42E113D8E4C49775DE2172054A1D505B777F691EEDA493FBD1B982148F59ECB28D730ED46E19F8BD3AF7A37046D73D462907AF535ED2DC3F80CD6B9681717D9DAD7BD919FAA8BD57B5C7A6EACC0E0EDE956004762C1BD2E76F9D26B9C4036B0A4C903DC02BCFEE341151D6E0A35D748CE4D4FB3C1B84FF58A196E85F78477DF%0d%0aHTTP_HOST%3alocalhost%3a50305%0d%0aHTTP_REFERER%3ahttp%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305%2fGraph%0d%0aHTTP_USER_AGENT%3aMozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit%2f537.22+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f25.0.1364.172+Safari%2f537.22%0d%0aHTTP_ORIGIN%3ahttp%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305%0d%0aHTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH%3aXMLHttpRequest%0d%0a&ALL_RAW=Connection%3a+keep-alive%0d%0aContent-Length%3a+99%0d%0aContent-Type%3a+application%2fx-www-form-urlencoded%3b+charset%3dUTF-8%0d%0aAccept%3a+*%2f*%0d%0aAccept-Charset%3a+ISO-8859-9%2cutf-8%3bq%3d0.7%2c*%3bq%3d0.3%0d%0aAccept-Encoding%3a+gzip%2cdeflate%2csdch%0d%0aAccept-Language%3a+tr-TR%2ctr%3bq%3d0.8%2cen-US%3bq%3d0.6%2cen%3bq%3d0.4%0d%0aCookie%3a+FunnelWeb%3d44D66957AF9E021D68F011F7EA89CF99585363E067264B4A9B2B60FB51030DFA64EAA943529D3352875332394F24293162CBFE088352F1169202E0806155F66F370237D16A787AB8E76417B72808F34FEC9B5133D1D56D0839B614F2E231AB8DE23FE3BB7C048BAA3FCEEDABD4A2A6ACCB1D76DEB657B3B8575A664823DA24044F67C096206D04CBD5971BAE21684EA3FE2CAA747A1C8C563692DBE6335A0948%3b+.ASPXAUTH%3dC42E113D8E4C49775DE2172054A1D505B777F691EEDA493FBD1B982148F59ECB28D730ED46E19F8BD3AF7A37046D73D462907AF535ED2DC3F80CD6B9681717D9DAD7BD919FAA8BD57B5C7A6EACC0E0EDE956004762C1BD2E76F9D26B9C4036B0A4C903DC02BCFEE341151D6E0A35D748CE4D4FB3C1B84FF58A196E85F78477DF%0d%0aHost%3a+localhost%3a50305%0d%0aReferer%3a+http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305%2fGraph%0d%0aUser-Agent%3a+Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit%2f537.22+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f25.0.1364.172+Safari%2f537.22%0d%0aOrigin%3a+http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305%0d%0aX-Requested-With%3a+XMLHttpRequest%0d%0a&APPL_MD_PATH=&APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH=C%3a%5cUsers%5cariza%5cDesktop%5cMasa%u00fcst%u00fc%5cosos_plus_2%5cOsos-21.11.2012%5cOsosPlus2.UI%5cOsosPlus2.UI%5c&AUTH_TYPE=Forms&AUTH_USER=KIPA&AUTH_PASSWORD=&LOGON_USER=CTS%5cariza&REMOTE_USER=KIPA&CERT_COOKIE=&CERT_FLAGS=&CERT_ISSUER=&CERT_KEYSIZE=&CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE=&CERT_SERIALNUMBER=&CERT_SERVER_ISSUER=&CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT=&CERT_SUBJECT=&CONTENT_LENGTH=99&CONTENT_TYPE=application%2fx-www-form-urlencoded%3b+charset%3dUTF-8&GATEWAY_INTERFACE=&HTTPS=&HTTPS_KEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER=&HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT=&INSTANCE_ID=&INSTANCE_META_PATH=&LOCAL_ADDR=%3a%3a1&PATH_INFO=%2fGraph%2f_IrregularChart&PATH_TRANSLATED=C%3a%5cUsers%5cariza%5cDesktop%5cMasa%u00fcst%u00fc%5cosos_plus_2%5cOsos-21.11.2012%5cOsosPlus2.UI%5cOsosPlus2.UI%5cGraph%5c_IrregularChart&QUERY_STRING=&REMOTE_ADDR=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_HOST=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_PORT=&REQUEST_METHOD=POST&SCRIPT_NAME=%2fGraph%2f_IrregularChart&SERVER_NAME=localhost&SERVER_PORT=50305&SERVER_PORT_SECURE=0&SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP%2f1.1&SERVER_SOFTWARE=&URL=%2fGraph%2f_IrregularChart&HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive&HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH=99&HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=application%2fx-www-form-urlencoded%3b+charset%3dUTF-8&HTTP_ACCEPT=*%2f*&HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET=ISO-8859-9%2cutf-8%3bq%3d0.7%2c*%3bq%3d0.3&HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip%2cdeflate%2csdch&HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=tr-TR%2ctr%3bq%3d0.8%2cen-US%3bq%3d0.6%2cen%3bq%3d0.4&HTTP_COOKIE=FunnelWeb%3d44D66957AF9E021D68F011F7EA89CF99585363E067264B4A9B2B60FB51030DFA64EAA943529D3352875332394F24293162CBFE088352F1169202E0806155F66F370237D16A787AB8E76417B72808F34FEC9B5133D1D56D0839B614F2E231AB8DE23FE3BB7C048BAA3FCEEDABD4A2A6ACCB1D76DEB657B3B8575A664823DA24044F67C096206D04CBD5971BAE21684EA3FE2CAA747A1C8C563692DBE6335A0948%3b+.ASPXAUTH%3dC42E113D8E4C49775DE2172054A1D505B777F691EEDA493FBD1B982148F59ECB28D730ED46E19F8BD3AF7A37046D73D462907AF535ED2DC3F80CD6B9681717D9DAD7BD919FAA8BD57B5C7A6EACC0E0EDE956004762C1BD2E76F9D26B9C4036B0A4C903DC02BCFEE341151D6E0A35D748CE4D4FB3C1B84FF58A196E85F78477DF&HTTP_HOST=localhost%3a50305&HTTP_REFERER=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305%2fGraph&HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit%2f537.22+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f25.0.1364.172+Safari%2f537.22&HTTP_ORIGIN=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50305&HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH=XMLHttpRequest}  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}

Why object is null in controller and why params are looking like above?

**UPDATE**

DTO

```
public class IrregularChartParams
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public int MeterTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ReadingTypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int DateRangeId { get; set; }
}
```

before it was working, then I change properties names, not it does not work...

Thanks.

Comment: See [ASP.NET - ActionResult parameter is coming back null always when passing string - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849624/asp-net-actionresult-parameter-is-coming-back-null-always-when-passing-string)

Comment: @Tomalak , my controller action is firing, there is no problem about that.

Comment: does IrregularChartParams take any params to constructor?

Comment: @DaveA, It was working before, but now does not work, I updated the question. Please review and suggest me somethig to do to fix this problem...

Comment: Yes, I removed dataType:"json" and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

you can directly pass object in data opton of ajax no need to stringfy..

try this

```
data: IrregularChartParams , //here
```

and get it by POST in you controller

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your DTO, the StartDate and EndDate properties are DateTime objects while you seem to be passing in strings from your JavaScript implementation.  This might be a cause for model binding to fail.

Comment: thanks for reply. I did not make any change, but it works now, codes are fully same, but work. I will be crazy...

Comment: Hmm...maybe you just needed a clean recompile?