# Route config doesn't take the parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this Action in the controller MattinaleController:

```
public ActionResult Modifica(int id)
{
    // manipulate data from repository

    return RedirectToAction("Modifica", "Modifica");
}
```

and this is my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Mattinale", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "ModificaComunicazione/{IDArticolazione}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Mattinale", action = "Modifica" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "{anno}/{mese}/{giorno}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Mattinale", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I start debugging and try to call the route `myHost/ModificaComunicazione/5` (random number here), I get this error (translated):

> Parameters dictionary contains Null value for parameter 'id' of non
>   nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Modifica(Int32)' in 'Mattinale.WebUI.Controllers.MattinaleController'

Looks like it doesn't take the parameter. What am I missing?!

Thanks, Davide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go through this link. [Route config doesn't take the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/849666/9994702). Param name should be same as which define in actions.

Comment: Of course! I called the parameter "id" while "IDArticolazione" was expected as set in the route config. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Davide, Yes you get the id param from the url but not send to the redirection. you should send your id parameter to the RedirectToAction methods. 
Check out: [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: No, I don't get the ID param from the url, that's the point. If I modify the parameter to be optional Modifica(int id = 0), I don't get any error but the id value will always be 0... it is not passed from url to action, there must be something wrong with the routing configuration.

Comment: There is something wrong in your clarification that you call **ModificaComunicazione** action and there is nothing about it in your question. So I guess you call it first and in the action you redirect to the second action called **Modifica** But you did not passed int value from the first action to the second one. So you get the error I think. When you set the param as id = 0 you get the default vaue and it is work properly

Comment: I don't call any **ModificaComunicazione** action, that's just an alias for calling the Modifica action in the Mattinale controller directly from url. BTW the question was answered.